# Select EntireColumn from ActiveCell, except first 3 rows

Tags: vba, excel, select

I would like to select a complete column from an ActiveCell except the first 3 rows, because they are always filled with descriptions/headerlines. I know ActiveCell and EntireColumn, but i don't know how to combine the commands to come to a solution.

So I have 10 columns to be filled with data, and when the user wants to work on a specific column, i would love to have it so he just needs to click on any cell in the column and then my macro selects the rest.

Perhaps the entire column is not the best idea, since I need to add comments to EVERY cell and Excel does not like that. 1000 rows will do it.

[image: Column select]

Comment: You should have enough reps to attach a pic

Comment: if you don't want to use EntireColumn, you can to set the range like Set rng = Range(Cells(4, ActiveCell.Column), Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, ActiveCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row, ActiveCell.Column))
<br> tips, don't repeat ActiveCell.Column, set a variable

Comment: picture attached. im gonna try that @Fabrizio. Thanks for the answers so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Resize(Rows.Count - 3).Offset(3).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: this works perfect for my original request @EntireColumn as well as for my actual problem (delimit rows to X). i used ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Resize(1000).Offset(3).Select for my solution. thank you so much! i love this community.